# Skip first row of data in IDL

Tags: plot, data-manipulation, idl-programming-language

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
0.000000     0.000000
1123.65      9.86156
1123.91      11.6620
1124.17      11.0899
1124.43      12.7743
1124.69      13.1157
1124.94      12.4047
1125.20      14.4865
1125.46      9.71926
1125.72      8.83414
1125.98      12.2079
1126.24      10.3670
1126.50      8.72245
1126.76      10.2243
1127.02      10.2417
```

I'm using `readcol` to read the data, the first column in `rest_wavelength` and the second column is of `flux`. The plot is distrubed because of the first `0.0000` row, how can I skip this row in IDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably to use `SKIPLINE` on `READCOL`, i.e.:

```
readcol, filename, rest_wavelength, flux, skipline=1
```

You could also just index after the fact:

```
rest_wavelength = rest_wavelength[1:*]
flux = flux[1:*]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the trick.  
btw a method that I found before coming back here was to use `remove` command, i.e.: `remove, 0, rest_wavelength, flux`.

Comment: one thing that I'd want to ask is what if I only want to keep one specific line?

Comment: You could always grab a single element with `flux[5]`.